# Next.js e.startsWith() warning on heroku

Tags: heroku, next.js, typeerror, warnings

I am working on a Next.js app and have been running into this warning on my browser console.
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.startsWith is not a function`

I don't use the `e.startsWith` function anywhere on my Next.js app and this error does not show up on my local environment.
This warning only shows up when I navigate between pages in my app on higher environments that are hosted by heroku.
I use heroku-20 stack and Next.js is at version 12.1.6

Does anyone know what might be up with this?

I have tried reading over heroku stacks or Next.js updates but none of these point to the warning I am seeing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the full traceback.